# Oracle SQL Missing Comma

Tags: sql, oracle

Probably a dumb question, but I am somewhat stuck even after looking at all the duplicate questions of this one...

```
INSERT INTO a.table 
    (id1, id2, lastupdate) 
    VALUES 
    (0987123456, 1234567890, CURRENT_DATE());
```

This gives me a missing comma error. Syntax looks good to me, id1 and id2 are NUMBER(10,0) and lastupdate is a date. Any insights? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO a.table (id1, id2, lastupdate)
VALUES (0987123456, 1234567890, CURRENT_DATE);
```

You don't need `()` after `current_date`.

P. S. And yes, it is a bit dumb question ;)  Just go to google.com, type "oracle current_date" and see examples...

Comment: Thank you, will accept in 10 minutes. What a great piece of technology, "missing comma".

Comment: Nice catch +1. you can as well use `NOW()` instead of `current_date`

Comment: oracle sql doesnt accept now() (its what I tried at first since I use mysql most of the time)

Comment: There is no function `NOW` in oracle. `CURRENT_DATE` is a function from SQL standard, but usually function `SYSDATE` is used. You can see it in most of examples in documentation or in articles in the web.